# Should we add the homework tag to a question?

Tags: discussion, tagging, homework

If I see a series of questions that are clearly homework (from my class!!!), should I tag them as such?

If so, what should I say in the summary so it doesn't get rejected?

Comment: My personal take is it's much better to comment that the question(s) seem to be homework from a class you're currently taking. I'm still subscribed to the "only the OP should add [tag:homework] to his question" bit...

Comment: "my class" meaning the one you are taking? or the one you are teaching?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Lol, I meant the former. xD

Comment: @J.M.: Hm...  why?

Comment: I've added the tag if someone wrote that it was a homework question but didn't tag it.

Comment: I add [tag:homework] if the OP explicitly states or even hints at it being one. If it's unfair, let the OP remove that. (I also drop in a comment about this issue.)

Comment: The homework tag no longer exists, as of a few months ago.  This thread is obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen several comments like J.M.'s here on meta.MSE saying that the homework tag should only be added by the OP, or after the OP has said that it is homework.  A possible reason is that false positives could be seen as insulting.  But I still see people adding the homework tag to others' questions without the OP having said that it is homework, and there doesn't seem to be a consensus.

I'm very interested in other people's views on this.

---

Here are a couple of related discussions from meta.SO:

[Definitive answer regarding retagging homework questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79475/definitive-answer-regarding-retagging-homework-questions)

[Etiquette on retagging questions as homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41393/etiquette-on-retagging-questions-as-homework)

(More can be found in the links there.)

Comment: I recently removed a homework tag that A added to B's question, while asking B to kindly restore the tag if the question was, indeed, homework.

Comment: It looks like shortly afterward C suggested an edit to put the tag back in, and D approved it.

Comment: Hmm.... I'll have to go delete it again. This means war!